# Сравнивание ячеек тега <table>

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер. код работает корректно до тех пор пока не ставить символ в конце перечисленных строк , если даже сразу ставить в конце , выдаёт true  , понимаю это связанно  с этой частью кода   `table.rows[k].cells[i].innerHTML=="X"`(и всеми остальными сравнениями innerHTML с "X") . Как мне быть ?

```
function proverka(){
var table = document.getElementById( "myTable" );
var flag; 
for ( var k = 0; k<tdQuan; k++){
    for ( var i = 0; i < tdQuan; i++ ) {
        for ( var j = 0; j < tdQuan; j++ ) {

if (table.rows[k].cells[i].innerHTML == table.rows[k].cells[j].innerHTML && table.rows[k].cells[i].innerHTML=="X" ||
 table.rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML == table.rows[i].cells[k].innerHTML &&   table.rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML=="X"  ||
 table.rows[j].cells[j].innerHTML == "X")
flag = true; 
else {
flag = false; 
continue; 
    }

  }

 if (flag === true){alert("победа " );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (...) {
  alert("победа");
  return;
}
```

Comment: я уже неделю не мог нормально спать из за этой нерешённой задачи , выручили, а я всё по другой дороге шёл  , спасибо Игорь

Comment: ошибся , сейчас выдаёт только при  клике на первую ячейку первой строки (если даже первый кликать его)